# Passing an instantiated object to a service via the constructer

Tags: symfony

I want to pass an initated object to a service, i want that instance of the object, i also want to set the object in a property so i can retreieve it afterwards, hence why i am passing it in the constructor.

Here is my services.yml

```
services:
    LoginService:
        class: Snap\ModelBundle\Service\Login
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@ExampleModelBundle.lib.Example.Ex"]
```

The second augment does not get passed, it gets passed a string path.

How do i pass the second augment which is an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service just for the class like..

```
instance.of.class:
    class: The\Class
    calls:  // if any.. or arguments..
        - [ setThing, [ blahblah ]]
```

and then it can be used as an argument as `@instance.of.class`

Comment: Yes, but this creates a new instance of it, does it not ?

Comment: The first time yes. After it is always referencing that same one like any service.